# Keep Getting "Index Out of Range"

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, dafny, dutch-national-flag-problem

So I've tried implementing a program for a simplified Dutch flag problem in Dafny where all indices 0 <= n < k are red and all indices k <= n < arr.Length are blue, except it keeps saying that k might go out of bounds even though it should be at most arr.Length based on how I coded it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
method dutch(arr: array?<char>) returns (k: int)
requires arr != null && forall x :: 0 <= x < arr.Length ==> arr[x] == 'r' || arr[x] == 'b'
ensures k <= arr.Length     //postcondition might not hold
ensures forall n :: 0 <= n < k ==> arr[n] == 'r'     //out of range
ensures forall n :: k <= n < arr.Length ==> arr[n] == 'b'     //out of range
modifies arr
{
  var x := 0;
  k := 0;
  while(x < arr.Length)
  invariant k <= x
  invariant forall n :: 0 <= n < k ==> arr[n] == 'r'     //out of range
  invariant forall n :: k <= n < x ==> arr[n] == 'b'     //invariant might not be maintained by loop
  {
    if(arr[x] == 'r')
    {
      arr[x] := arr[k];
      arr[k] := 'r';
      k := k + 1;
    }
    x := x + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the loop, all that is known is the invariant and the negation of the loop guard. So, `arr.Length <= x` holds and so does `k <= x`. So, according to your loop specification, `x` might be `arr.Length + 10` and `k` might be `arr.Length + 2`.

To verify the program, you need to turn your belief that `k` "should be at most `arr.Length` based on how I coded it" into a loop specification. So, add

```
invariant k <= arr.Length
```